# Static sound through HTPC Speakers

Tags: windows-7, audio, hdmi, windows-media-center, htpc

I just built a Home Theater PC running Windows 7 with MediaBrowser.

When I open Media Center, I get this static noise coming through the TV. This is before I have even played anything. It only happens with Media Center open. It sort of sounds like fan noise but does not increase when the fan RPM rises.

The build is:

- MB: ECS A75F-M2
- CPU: AMD A6-3500
- RAM: GSKILL 2GB
- PSU: ANTEC Eco 450
- HDD: Samsung SSD 830 series + a bunch of random drives

The connection to TV is HDMI via the built in ATI HD graphics.

Software:

- MediaBrowser
- uTorrent
- CoreTemp
- Shark007

Has anyone heard of this? I think it is strange when its just happening as soon as I open Media Center. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of "white noise" like I presume, not the static sound but the noise you get with most TV's should a extremely bright (white) screen comes up, just adjust your volume controls to a lower setting and it should get rid of it no problem, I experienced the same thing and that's all I had to do.

Comment: Ok, but is it normal to happen only when I open media center, even when I am not playing anything? I don't get it with WMP at all.  

When you say adjust your volume controls, I am assuming you dont just mean turn the volume down?

I just think it is strange as I never had it with the laptop I was using as a HTPC before this.

Comment: There are variables that can affect if you end up withe the problem, to be honest it's something you don't come across all to often.